# Spawn node child_process with named pipe as stdin

Tags: node.js, named-pipes

Say I have a named pipe on linux:

```
mkfifo lk.log
```

From the command line, I can do this to print out anything written to the name pipe file.

```
node monitor.js < lk.log
```

and pretend this is what the script looks like

```
// monitor.js

process.stdin.resume();
process.stdin.setEncoding('utf8');

// read data from stdin
process.stdin.on('data', function(chunk) {
    console.log(chunk);
});
```

**How could I do this within node using** `child_process.spawn`**?**

```
child_process.spawn('node', ['monitor.js'])...
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is to use `fs.open` and the stdio options in `child_process.spawn` as such:

```
var spawn = require('child_process').spawn;

var fd_stdin = fs.openSync('lk.log', 'r');
spawn('node', ['monitor.js'], {
    stdio: [fd_stdin, 1, 2];
});
```

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way would be to use `exec()`:

```
var exec = require('child_process').exec;

exec('node monitor.js < lk.log', function(err, stdout, stderr) {
  ...
});
```

A more elaborate way would be to open the named pipe in node and pass it as stdin to the process you're spawning (see [the option `stdio` for spawn](http://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html#child_process_child_process_spawn_command_args_options)).

Comment: `child_process.exec` does not help me because it waits for the child process to terminate before being able to read from child's stdout.

Comment: Oops, you are correct. I guess checking out the stdio option for spawn is your only option.

Answer (score 0):

From Ben Noordhuis (Core Node contributor) - 10/11/11

> Windows has a concept of named pipes but since you mention `mkfifo` I
>   assume you mean UNIX FIFOs.
>
> We don't support them and probably never will (FIFOs in non-blocking
>   mode have the potential to deadlock the event loop) but you can use
>   UNIX sockets if you need similar functionality.

https://groups.google.com/d/msg/nodejs/9TvDwCWaB5c/udQPigFvmgAJ

For unix sockets, see: https://stackoverflow.com/a/18226566/977939