# Passing string stored in memory to pdftotext, antiword, catdoc, etc

Tags: node.js, pdf, text, child-process

Is it possible to call CLI tools like pdftotext, antiword, catdoc (text extractor scripts) passing a string instead of a file?

Currently, I read PDF files calling pdftotext with `child_process.spawn`. I spawn a new process and store the result in a new variable. Everything works fine.

I’d like to pass the `binary` from a `fs.readFile` instead of the file itself:

```
fs.readFile('./my.pdf', (error, binary) => {
    // Call pdftotext with child_process.spawn passing the binary.
    let event = child_process.spawn('pdftotext', [
        // Args here!
    ]);
});
```

How can I do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's definitely possible, if the command can handle piped input.

[spawn](https://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html#child_process_child_process_spawn_command_args_options) returns a [ChildProcess](https://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html#child_process_class_childprocess) object, you can pass the string (or binary) in memory to it by write to its [stdin](https://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html#child_process_child_stdin). The string should be [converted](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13230487/4578017) to a [ReadableStream](https://nodejs.org/api/stream.html#stream_readable_streams) first, then you can write the string to `stdin` of the CLI by [pipe](https://nodejs.org/api/stream.html#stream_readable_pipe_destination_options).

[createReadStream](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_createreadstream_path_options) creates a [ReadableStream](https://nodejs.org/api/stream.html#stream_readable_streams) from a file.

The following example download a pdf file and pipe the content to `pdftotext`, then show first few bytes of the result.

```
const source = 'http://static.googleusercontent.com/media/research.google.com/en//archive/gfs-sosp2003.pdf'
const http = require('http')
const spawn = require('child_process').spawn

download(source).then(pdftotext)
.then(result => console.log(result.slice(0, 77)))

function download(url) {
  return new Promise(resolve => http.get(url, resolve))
}

function pdftotext(binaryStream) {
  //read input from stdin and write to stdout
  const command = spawn('pdftotext', ['-', '-'])
  binaryStream.pipe(command.stdin)

  return new Promise(resolve => {
    const result = []
    command.stdout.on('data', chunk => result.push(chunk.toString()))
    command.stdout.on('end', () => resolve(result.join('')))
  })
}
```

For CLIs have no option to read from `stdin`, you can use [named pipes](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11750041/4578017).

Edit: Add another example with named pipes.

Once the named pipes are created, you can use them like files. The following example creates temporary named pipes to send input and get output, and show first few bytes of the result.

```
const fs = require('fs')
const spawn = require('child_process').spawn

pipeCommand({
  name: 'wvText',
  input: fs.createReadStream('document.doc'),
}).then(result => console.log(result.slice(0, 77)))

function createPipe(name) {
  return new Promise(resolve =>
    spawn('mkfifo', [name]).on('exit', () => resolve()))
}

function pipeCommand({name, input}) {
  const inpipe = 'input.pipe'
  const outpipe = 'output.pipe'
  return Promise.all([inpipe, outpipe].map(createPipe)).then(() => {
    const result = []
    fs.createReadStream(outpipe)
    .on('data', chunk => result.push(chunk.toString()))
    .on('error', console.log)

    const command = spawn(name, [inpipe, outpipe]).on('error', console.log)
    input.pipe(fs.createWriteStream(inpipe).on('error', console.log))
    return new Promise(resolve =>
      command.on('exit', () => {
        [inpipe, outpipe].forEach(name => fs.unlink(name))
        resolve(result.join(''))
      }))
  })
}
```

Comment: Hei @DarkKnight, tranks a lot!! If i'm not askinh to much, could u provide a working exemple with named pipes? It turns out that i'm using other scripts that doesnt support the other method.

Comment: All of the tools you mentioned can accept `stdin` by specifying `-`. I added another example, anyway.

Comment: Hei DarkKnight, some how i'm seeing ```events.js:160
      throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
      ^

Error: EPIPE: broken pipe, write
    at Error (native)``` now... do you know what could be this?

Comment: Most likely the command exits before consuming all input data(and EOF), to inspect it further, you can add `.on('error' ...` to streams and the child process.

Comment: It's returning ```{ Error: EPIPE: broken pipe, write
    at Error (native) errno: -32, code: 'EPIPE', syscall: 'write' }```... is it working on your machine?

Comment: All of the examples works(node v6.4.0 on Linux). What command and input data did you use? Does it work with regular input file?

Comment: Is working with regular input file. I'm using the antiword script with your script. I'm trying also to do the following: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/EyBLWa?editors=0110 (which is a example of i will do in my app)

Comment: If i try to read a "real" file, everything will work just fine.

Comment: `cat document.doc > input.pipe & antiword input.pipe`, `antiword` says: I can't get the size of 'input.pipe'. It tries to seek, but pipes are non-seekable.

Comment: So, it's a antiword problem. Is it fixable?

Comment: There is something really strange.. i can't execute antiword, but i can read the file with fs.readFile? lol.. :X

Comment: This is really not that strange, @FXAMN. Pipes are not seekable, while ordinary files are. When reading a PDF file, you often need to seek, unless you are OK with reading the whole file into memory (in which case you may have hard time processing large PDFs). Many tools accept input from a pipe, but they write it immediately into a file and only then process it.