# node fs.writeFileSync() never returns

Tags: node.js, typescript, fs, mkfifo

I'm creating a pipe and trying to write to it. But the writing never works.

```
import * as fs from 'fs';
import * as mkfifo from 'mkfifo';

mkfifo.mkfifoSync('/tmp/my_fifo', 0o600);

fs.writeFileSync('/tmp/my_fifo', 'Hey there!');

console.log('here');
```

If I comment everything except `mkfifo.mkfifoSync('/tmp/my_fifo', 0o600);` I see the pipe is created ok.

However, `fs.writeFileSync('/tmp/my_fifo', 'Hey there!');` never returns.

Even when I use the callback version `fs.writeFile()1 the callback is never fired.

```
fs.writeFile('/tmp/my_fifo', 'Hey there!', (err) => {
    if (err) {
        return console.log('Write error: ' + err);
    }

    console.log('Write success');

    process.exit();
});
```

The callback is never called.

What am I doing wrong?

Just as a check I open up and tried to read the pipe from another script:

```
fs.readFile('/tmp/my_fifo', (err, data) => {
    if (err) {
        return console.log('Read error: ' + err);
    }

    console.log('Read success. Data is: ' + data);
});
```

On the writer side I see the error:

```
Error: ESPIPE: invalid seek, write
```

On the reader side I see:

```
Read success. Data is:
```

empty data, but a successful read.

**Update**

If I don't create the pipe at all via `mkfifoSync()`, and instead just call `fs.writeFileSync()`, it will create and write to the file just fine.

So my question is how do I write to this pipe?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you have to use the `appendFileSync` method not the `writeFileSync` method for writing to a named pipe

append to named pipes

```
const fs = require("fs");
const mkfifo = require("mkfifo");

mkfifo.mkfifoSync("/tmp/my_fifo", 0o600);
fs.appendFileSync("/tmp/my_fifo", "hello world", ...);
```

read from named pipes

```
const fs = require("fs");
console.log(fs.readFileSync("/tmp/my_fifo").toString());
```

Comment: I'm actually using https://www.npmjs.com/package/mkfifo for fifo creation and fs.appendFileSync("/tmp/my_fifo", "hello world", ...); has the same problems....it just hangs.

Comment: reading from the named pipe is a separate script, writing to the named pipe is also a separate script, you have to execute the writing part before the reading part

Comment: @lostdorje did you put the same code snippet in one file?

Comment: I have 2 scripts. The writing one just hangs. (Shouldn't matter though -- writing and reading can be done in a single script because the '*Sync' versions of all methods are being used).

When I remove the mkfifo.mkfifoSync("/tmp/my_fifo", 0o600); everything works fine, except it's not a pipe, it's a regular file.

Comment: did you confirm if `/tmp/my_fifo` was actually created ?

Comment: yep:

prw-------  1 myuser  wheel  0 Feb 22 09:53 /tmp/my_fifo

and we can see it's a pipe. the writeFileSync() and appendFileSync() both just hang. after mkfifo.mkfifoSync() creates the pipe.

there are other older SO posts claiming Node doesn't support Named Pipes, perhaps that still holds true.

see: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11750041/how-to-create-a-named-pipe-in-node-js

Comment: i don't think so, it runs here without glitch

Comment: version is v8.9.3 on mac os x 0.13.2

Comment: ha! thanks for the proof. i needed that. i have no idea. i noticed some small differences between your code and mine and just copied your code directly and it worked. then i started changing it back to my original code piece by piece and sure enough it still worked! the point at which it stopped working was switching from appendFileSync() to writeFileSync(). which is what you stated to begin with. that's the first change i made to get my stuff working, but it didn't...but when i used your code sample and backed it up into my code, it all started working. derp. thanks! :-)