# How to send a signal from a terminal window to a webscraper running on Puppeteer/Node.js on Raspberry Pi

Tags: node.js, terminal, raspberry-pi, puppeteer

I am running a simple web scraper written in Puppeteer / Node.js on a Raspberry Pi. It downloads data from a websites at 6pm and 6am every day. Every so often, say once a week, I'd like to send a command or signal or something telling it to download the data immediately. This presumably would be be a command from another terminal window. The question is how do I do this? I could write a small file and have the program constantly look out for the file, but this seems very crude. Is there a better way? Something simple please as I'm a bit of a novice!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Keeping in mind that I don't actually recommend doing this in most cases, as discussed in my [previous answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/78103668/6243352), here's a contrived example to illustrate the `readline` approach.

```js
const puppeteer = require("puppeteer"); // ^22.2.0
const readline = require("readline");
const {setTimeout} = require("node:timers/promises");

const rl = readline.createInterface({
  input: process.stdin,
  output: process.stdout,
});

const getPageTitle = async (
  url = "https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Special:Random"
) => {
  let browser;

  try {
    browser = await puppeteer.launch();
    const [page] = await browser.pages();
    await page.goto(url, {waitUntil: "domcontentloaded"});
    return await page.title();
  }
  finally {
    await browser?.close();
  }
};

rl.on("line", async line => {
  try {
    console.log(`  Received command from stdin: \`${line}\``);
    console.log("  Command result:", await getPageTitle(line));
  }
  catch (err) {
    console.error(err);
  }
});

(async () => {
  for (;;) {
    try {
      console.log(await getPageTitle());
    }
    catch (err) {
      console.error(err);
    }
    await setTimeout(20_000);
  }
})();

// execute with: `cat | node script.js` to enable the below behavior
console.log(
  `to send command: echo 'https://www.stackoverflow.com' > /proc/${process.pid}/fd/0`
);
console.log("_".repeat(80));
```

This prints a random Wikipedia page title every 20 seconds while also listening to stdin for additional URLs to print titles for. With the script running on a single terminal, type in `https://stackoverflow.com` to see it print `Stack Overflow - Where Developers Learn, Share, & Build Careers`, for example.

Now, if you run it with `cat | node script.js` to provide a pipe as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32643326/6243352), you can send commands to it from another terminal with `echo 'https://www.stackoverflow.com' > /proc/{pid}/fd/0` where `{pid}` is printed dynamically by the program at startup, or obtainable with `pgrep node`.

Comment: This is exactly what I need! But for some reason rl.on() never gets executed. I run node readline.js in one terminal, and echo a string from another terminal. The string appears in the first terminal, but the "Received command. from stdin .. " is never executed. I shortened that routine to console.log('hello world') and that still doesn't get executed. Any idea why not? Apologies, am a bit of a novice in node.js

Comment: Did you run the program with `cat | your-script.js`? Did you try running the exact same code as me? If you have custom code, can you open a new question with your code as a [mcve]? If you are running the exact same code/command as me and it's still not working, please provide your Node version, package.json, Pi system details and commands you ran on the terminal. I'm running on Ubuntu 22.04 and haven't tested on a Pi, although I have access to an old Pi B+ if necessary (it shouldn't matter).

Comment: Apologies, I hadn't done he cat| bit. Stupid me, as they say, when all else fails read the instructions! It makes more sense now as well. Incredibly helpful, exactly what I need, thank you!

Answer (score 1):

This seems like an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem/233676#233676). Does the script really need to be running continuously in the first place? The normal way to set this up is to make the script one shot (it scrapes the data once and exits immediately when you run `node your-script.js`), then set up a [cron job](https://bc-robotics.com/tutorials/setting-cron-job-raspberry-pi/) to run it at 6 AM and 6 PM daily. Then, when you need that "extra" run at a random additional time, you can simply run `node your-script.js`.

By running fresh each time, you don't have to worry about keeping the process alive and dealing with slow memory leaks, etc. There's no extra code to write for looping, scheduling, sleeping and timing since that's all done by cron.

If you want to go for the "hard" way you're proposing (it's not actually hard, just less elegant than the above suggestion), where the script runs continuously, scrapes twice a day, and should listen for an extra command to trigger a run at an arbitrary time, you could use one of many techniques:

- File [watching](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13698043/observe-file-changes-with-node-js) (rather than polling)
- Listening to stdin with [`readline`](https://nodejs.org/api/readline.html) and running `echo 'some command' > /proc/{PID}/fd/0` as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5380763/6243352) to send a command to your program
- Opening a socket (with [net](https://nodejs.org/api/net.html) or [udp](https://nodejs.org/api/dgram.html)) and [writing to the socket from the terminal or another script](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/336876/simple-shell-script-to-send-socket-message)
- Creating and writing to a [named pipe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11750041/how-to-create-a-named-pipe-in-node-js)
- Running a [web server on localhost](https://nodejs.org/api/http.html) and sending HTTP requests to it (say, with `curl`).

Other approaches are possible, but this should give you some starting ideas if you're curious or the cron job approach doesn't work for your use case for some reason.

---

Taking a further step back, do you even need a Raspberry Pi for this? For once-daily scraping, the best solution may be a [GitHub action](https://github.com/yasoob/github-action-scraper-tutorial/blob/main/.github/workflows/scrape.yml). An additional trigger could be done [manually](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/using-workflows/manually-running-a-workflow), or with the [API](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/using-workflows/manually-running-a-workflow#running-a-workflow-using-the-rest-api) or a [webhook](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/using-workflows/events-that-trigger-workflows).

Comment: Thank, there's actually more going on in the program than I said so it does need to just run, and currently runs for months without needing intervention. The readline looks like the best way, but how do I execute readline in the program without waiting? 99% of the time there will be nothing for it to receive! Do I just put it in a loop (without await) and it then when it gets an input it sets a variable in memory which gets picked up elsewhere?

Comment: No loops for [`readline`](https://nodejs.org/api/readline.html#event-line)--it's event-driven and non-blocking, so you chain your action from `rl.on("line", line => { /* parse 'line' string and call your func accordingly */ })`.